# colspan for select doesnt work in form table

Tags: html, forms, select, input, html-table

im creating a form with dropdown select i set to colspan 2 and expect its width to cover the 2 input field below but it didnt work
please someone show me what went wrong

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="ship">
        <table>
          <form action="">
            <tr colspan="2">
              <td>
                <select name="" id="">
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>
                    Select Your Country
                  </option>
                  <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
                  <option value="India">India</option>
                  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="State/Country" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Postcode/Zip" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </form>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="total"></div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `<td colspan="2">` and `<select name="" id="" style="width: 100%";>`